# How to compare int and timestamp column (Laravel eloquent)?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have the following code

```
$firstItem = ['events' => (object)['event_code' => 'reg', 'minutes_from' => 15, 'minutes_to' => 75 ]];
$set = DB::table('customers')->select('customers.idfa', 'customers.idfv', 'customers.app_build_number', 'customers.os_version', 'customers.model')->distinct()
    ->join('customer_events', 'customer_events.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->join('customer_event_types', 'customer_events.customer_event_type_id', 'customer_event_types.id')
    //     event      where
    ->when($firstItem, function ($query, $events) {
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            if (!isset($event->event_code) || empty($event->event_code)) {
                continue;
            }

            $query->where('customer_event_types.code', '=', $event->event_code);

            if (isset($event->minutes_from) && !empty($event->minutes_from) && is_numeric($event->minutes_from)) {
                $query->whereTime("customer_events.created_at", '<', Carbon::now()->subMinutes($event->minutes_from)->timestamp);
            }
            if (isset($event->minutes_to) && !empty($event->minutes_to) && is_numeric($event->minutes_to)) {
                $query->whereTime("customer_events.created_at", '>', Carbon::now()->addMinutes($event->minutes_to)->timestamp);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    })
    ->get();
```

But when I run it with the help of `tinker` I see the following error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "1566909353" (SQL: select distinct "customers"."idfa", "customers"."idfv", "customers"."app_build_number", "customers"."os_version", "customers"."model" from "customers" inner join "customer_events" on "customer_events"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" inner join "customer_event_types" on "customer_events"."customer_event_type_id" = "customer_event_types"."id" where "customer_event_types"."code" = reg and "customer_events"."created_at"::time < 1566909353 and "customer_events"."created_at"::time > 1566914753)'

I have SQL equivalent for this:

```
select customers.id, customers.idfa, customers.idfv, count(customer_events.id) as event_counter
      from "customers"
               inner join "customer_events" on "customer_events"."customer_id" = "customers"."id"
               inner join "customer_event_types"
                          on "customer_events"."customer_event_type_id" = "customer_event_types"."id"
      where "customer_event_types"."name" = 'Регистрация'
        and customer_events.created_at <
            (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (15 * interval '1 minute')) 
        and customer_events.created_at >
            (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (65 * interval '1 minute'))

      group by customers.id, customers.idfa, customers.idfv
```

It works. When I make `->toSql()` instead of get in the Eloquent query I see the following code:

```
select distinct "customers"."idfa",
                "customers"."idfv",
                "customers"."app_build_number",
                "customers"."os_version",
                "customers"."model"
from "customers"
         inner join "customer_events" on "customer_events"."customer_id" = "customers"."id"
         inner join "customer_event_types" on "customer_events"."customer_event_type_id" = "customer_event_types"."id"
where "customer_event_types"."code" = 'reg'
  and "customer_events"."created_at" < 1566908749
  and "customer_events"."created_at" > 1566914149
```

Here are integers that is not correct to compare with timestamps as I understand. 
How to explain for Eloquent, that I am going to compare timestamps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why cast the Carbon instance to a timestamp anyway? Let Laravels query builder handle the conversion of Carbon to the appropriate format for the database.

Just do

```
Carbon::now()->subMinutes($event->minutes_from)
```

instead of

```
Carbon::now()->subMinutes($event->minutes_from)->timestamp
```

in your query.